# WordPress single post template layout

Tags: wordpress, layout, sidebar

I'm not too famiiar with WordPress but, I've created the following page to display custom post types `single-opportunities.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying single opportunities posts.
 **/


get_header();
global $accesspresslite_options, $post;
$accesspresslite_settings = get_option( 'accesspresslite_options', $accesspresslite_options );
$post_class = get_post_meta( $post -> ID, 'accesspresslite_sidebar_layout', true );
?>

<div class="ak-container">
    <?php 
        if ($post_class=='both-sidebar') { ?>
            <div id="primary-wrap" class="clearfix"> 
        <?php }
    ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

            <?php // accesspresslite_post_nav(); ?>

            <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. 

            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

        <?php 
    get_sidebar('left'); 

        if ($post_class=='both-sidebar') { ?>
            </div> 
        <?php }

    ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've added a custom post type and this page is displaying the information OK, but the layout  has a sidebar on the right. I'm not sure why it is displaying the sidebar on the right? Can this default option be changed.

Ideally I'd like to edit the template above so the layout has a left sidebar, that I can then add a custom menu into.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like youre calling the sidebar after the main body of the post/page. Call it before to have it show up on the left side.

```
/**
* The Template for displaying single opporunities posts.
*
*/

get_header();
global $accesspresslite_options, $post;
$accesspresslite_settings = get_option( 'accesspresslite_options', 
$accesspresslite_options );
$post_class = get_post_meta( $post -> ID, 'accesspresslite_sidebar_layout', true );
 ?>

<div class="ak-container">
<?php 
    if ($post_class=='both-sidebar') { ?>
        <div id="primary-wrap" class="clearfix"> 
    <?php }
     get_sidebar('left'); 
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php // accesspresslite_post_nav(); ?>

        <?php
        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
        if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. 

        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php 

    if ($post_class=='both-sidebar') { ?>
        </div> 
    <?php }

?>
```